# Custom MBean in Tomcat - cannot find javaURLContextFactory when creating InitialContext

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, jmx, classnotfound

I've written a custom MBean that deploys in Tomcat 6. One of its tasks is to query a database value. I'm doing this by loading up the database resource using JNDI - the resource is defined in Tomcat's server.xml.

The problem is that when I create an instance of `javax.naming.InitialContext` it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` as it can't find `org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory`. 
This class is in `catalina.jar` and loaded by the common classloader. The jar containing my MBean code is loaded by a shared classloader.

Any ideas as to how I can get around this?

To note: my MBean is loaded by a ContextListener which I've defined in the `tomcat/conf/web.xml`. I've also defined it in a webapp `web.xml` which makes no difference. I can't really move my jar so as to be loaded by the common classloader as it relies on classes loaded by the shared classloader.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Comment: Can you publish the exact configuration? web.xml, server.xml and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks a weird classloading or security/permission issue. Below is a workaround.

The main idea: Since the `ServletContextListener` could call the `new InitialContext()` without the `ClassNotFoundException` get it in the listener and pass it to the constructor of the MBean object before you register the MBean. I used a simple web application and I have not modified `tomcat/conf/web.xml`.

Resource configuration in the `tomcat/conf/context.xml`:

```
<Context>
...
    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="root" password="..." driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest?autoReconnect=true"/>
...
<Context>
```

The `web.xml` resource configuration:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The `ServletContextListener` which registers the MBean:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private ObjectName objectName;

    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("---> bean context listener started");

        final MBeanServer mbeanServer = 
            ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        try {
            final InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            final Context envContext = 
                (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            objectName = new ObjectName("com.example:type=Hello");
            final Hello helloMbean = new Hello(envContext);
            mbeanServer.registerMBean(helloMbean, objectName);
            System.out.println("---> registerMBean ok");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("---> bean context listener destroyed");
        final MBeanServer mbeanServer = 
            ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        try {
            mbeanServer.unregisterMBean(objectName);
            System.out.println("---> unregisterMBean ok");
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MBean interface:

```
public interface HelloMBean {
    void sayHello();
}
```

MBean implementation:

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Hello implements HelloMBean {

    private final Context envContext;

    public Hello(final Context envContext) {
        this.envContext = envContext;
        System.out.println("new hello " + envContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("sayHello()");

        try {
            final DataSource ds = 
                (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
            final Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            System.out.println("   conn: " + conn);
            // more JDBC code
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The [MBean Descriptor How To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/mbeans-descriptor-howto.html) says a `mbeans-descriptor.xml` is required but it's worked without it well. I could connect to the HelloMBean with `jconsole`. Calling `sayHello()` through `jconsole` printed the following:

```
conn: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest?autoReconnect=true, \
UserName=root@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver
```

Sources:

- [MBeans and Tomcat: A HOWTO Guide for Managing YOUR Application](http://oss.wxnet.org/mbeans.html)
- [JNDI Datasource HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example)